# Include a file as parameters for a template

Tags: templates, azure-devops, yaml

I have a number of pipelines and jobs that use the same set of parameters for templates. The data is subject to change on occasion so I would prefer to have one location, i.e. a file, where I can store this and then use that either as a template parameter set or to generate a template parameter set. That way I don't have to jump across a bunch of files to change something, or hard code one template file with that info and be married to that template for anything that needs that parameter set.

What I want to do is something *like* this but I don't know how, or if I can:

jobs:

- job:
- template:
- includeFile: /path/filename.yml

where the file in question would list the parameters at compile or run time.

Is this a thing? Can someone detail how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this time, however, using a file directly as parameters for a template is not supported.

As an alternative method, you can use variable groups.

> Use a variable group to store values that you want to control and make available across multiple pipelines. You can also use variable groups to store secrets and other values that might need to be passed into a YAML pipeline.

Go to Pipelines/Library to create one. Then please add the name and value for each variable you want. For more detailed information and steps, please click [Add & use variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group).

After that, all you need to do is use them to assign values to template parameters.